# chef mysql install specific version

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, vagrant, chef-solo

I want to install mysql v5.5.27 and php v5.3.15 but opscode doesn't show how to do this.

I've checked the recipes and saw the attributes and modified them but still no results.
Is there a way to force this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PHP, if you want to install a different version from what is what is available in the distribution's official repository, you can use the compile from source install method instead of package (default).

Simply change `default['php']['install_method']` to `'source'` and run the default recipe. Alternatively explicitly run php::source ;-)

> NOTE: You also need to change the default['php']['url'], default['php']['version'], default['php']['checksum'], etc to suite your needs.

For MySQL, as Mark said, it is up to the distribution (the version from its repository), looking at the [mysql::server](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/mysql/blob/master/recipes/server.rb) there isn't easy way to change it, as there is no such option as PHP (install by compiling from source) like the PHP cookbook.

Answer (score 0):

The cookbook only has logic for choosing the version when installing on windows. On Linux the cookbook simply installs the mysql package supported by the package repositories associated with your distro.